# Does considered to be experimental - static reflection feature include iteration over parent classes?

Tags: c++, reflection, c++-ts

Studying information about possible new TS features I discovered the static reflection is considered to be added. [The document summing up the meeting on the proposals](https://www.meetingcpp.com/blog/items/reflections-on-the-reflection-proposals.html) gathers the information on what actually proposals intend to introduce and what authors believe should not be added:

> - Supported:
>
>   - Data members (e.g. iterating over the member variables)
>   - Member types (typedefs/using declarations)
>   - Enumerators
>   - Template instantiations
>   - Alias support
> - Not Supported
>
>   - Namespace member sequences
>   - Functions
>   - Class templates
>   - Building new datatypes
>   - Reflection facilities already in C++
>   - Anonymous Functions
>   - Attributes

My first thought was that the very basic reflection element - iterating over parent classes, is not included neither in supported nor not supported list. Are indeed none of the proposals request to add this one?

Comment: I do not believe so there is another ISO meeting soon.

Comment: You're welcome to read over the [papers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/). Reflection is being targeted for a TS, so it won't be in C++20.

Comment: @Barry Good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [Working Draft, C++ Extensions for Reflection](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/n4766.pdf) which is [currently being voted on](https://herbsutter.com/2018/11/13/trip-report-fall-iso-c-standards-meeting-san-diego/) to be published as the Reflection TS, there is a `concept Base` (see `[reflect.concepts.base]`), currently retrieved using

- `std::experimental::reflect::get_base_classes`
- `std::experimental::reflect::get_public_base_classes`
- `std::experimental::reflect::get_accessible_base_classes`

Comment: Heavy? If you mean the syntax, yeah. There's indications from Herb Sutter that the syntax will be changed to be more constexprish and less templatelish, see http://wg21.link/p1240, and moving from TS into the standard would remove `experimental` from the middle anyway.